# How can I manipulate an external query to Sql Server?

Tags: python, sql, sql-server

I have a procedure that I wrote in Sql Server. This procedure masks the data returned by the query that comes before it as a string. E.g :

```
exec datamasking 'select * from [user]'
```

I want the following if a query called select * from [user] comes to this database, I want to convert this query into a string and work like this:

```
exec datamasking 'query'
```

To give an example over Python, if I want to connect to the database and pull data like this:

```
import pyodbc

conn = pyodbc.connect(r'connectionstring')

cursor = conn.cursor()

cursor.execute("select * from [user]")
```

As you can see in the last line, when a query is thrown, I want this query to be declared in the database as follows:

```
exec datamasking 'select * from [user]'
```

If I get back together, I want to run the external query to the database with my procedure on the sql side and return the masked data to the user. How can I do that. I hope I was able to explain. I would be very happy if you help.

Comment: This feels like an [XY Problem](//xyproblem,info) and a statement like `exec datamasking 'select * from [user]'` looks like a SQL injection nightmare.

Comment: Perhaps instead of inventing an unbalanced and underinflated wheel, you could consider... [the feature called data masking](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/dynamic-data-masking)?